# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when workin with pyautogui

Tags: python, text, pyautogui

```
import keyboard
import pyautogui
characters = []
with open("pytest.txt", "r") as text:
    characters = text
print(characters)
def start():
    global breaktrue
    breaktrue = 'false'

start()


while True:
    global breaktrue
    if breaktrue == 'true':
        break
    if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
        for line in ([characters]):
            pyautogui.press(line)
            if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
                while True:
                    if keyboard.is_pressed('*'):
                        break
        breaktrue = 'true'
```

this is the code i am struggling with any ideas on how i get this to type the text containted in the pytest.txt file

Comment: Can you copy/paste the full error message including the traceback and the line number where the error happened? Also, can you give a sample of what is in pytest.txt? Is it a single line of text, multiple lines of text, or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error I see is here:

```
with open("pytest.txt", "r") as text:
    characters = text
```

The `text` variable contains the file object, not the text in the file object. You need to change the line to `characters = text.read()`.

Also, I would just get rid of the `start()` function entirely. You only call it once and all it does is set the global `breaktrue` variable. Replace the `start()` call with `breaktrue = 'true'`.

And actually, don't even use `'true'` and `'false'` string values, use the actual Boolean `True` and `False` values.